# Multi-line file shuffle

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file with empty lines separating blocks of text. I would like to use *NIX command-line tools to shuffle this file while respecting the block structure. In other words, in the output I would like to see the changed order of blocks; the lines and their order inside the block remain the same.

Input file example:

```
line 1
line 2

line 10
line 20
line 30

line 100
line 200
```

The output file (after shuffle):

```
line 10
line 20
line 30

line 1
line 2

line 100
line 200
```

Of course, running repeatedly should give different order of blocks.

The first line of the file is always non-empty. There are no double blank lines. The last line of the file is always empty.

I wrote a very simple Python script that reads all lines in a list of lists, shuffles it and outputs. I am curious whether I could do it with standard *NIX tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

POSIXly, you could do something like:

```
<file awk '
  BEGIN{srand(); n=rand()}
  {print n, NR, $0}
  !NF {n=rand()}
  END {if (NF) print n, NR+1, ""}' |
  sort -nk1 -k2 |
  cut -d' ' -f3-
```

That is, prefix each line with `<a-random-number-that-changes-with-each-paragraph>` then the line number, then sort numerically on the first number and then second to keep the line order in the paragraphs and remove those extra numbers.

One may want to pipe to `sed '$d'` to remove the trailing blank line.

Beware that with most `awk` implementations  `srand()` uses the unix epoch time to seed the pseudo-random number generator, so you may get the same result if run twice in the same second (a [historical bug now engraved in the POSIX spec, despite my efforts unfortunately](http://austingroupbugs.net/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=983)).

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU tools, this divides paragraphs into NUL-separated groups, shuffles them, and then removes the NULs:

```
$ sed '1s/^/\n/; s/^$/\x00/' input | shuf -z | sed '1d; s/\x00//'
line 100
line 200

line 10
line 20
line 30

line 1
line 2
```

#### Alternate approach not using NUL

Since not all tools support NUL characters, here is an alternative.  This reads in paragraphs, substitutes `~` for newlines, then shuffles, then converts the `~` back to newlines before displaying the results:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\n/, "~")} 1' RS= input | shuf | awk '{gsub(/~/, "\n")} 1' ORS="\n\n"
line 10
line 20
line 30

line 100
line 200

line 1
line 2
```

If your text might contain `~`, then use another character which the text will not contain as the temporary line separator.

Answer (score 5):

Using perl:

```
perl -MList::Util -00 -e 'chomp(my @a=<>); print join("\n\n", List::Util::shuffle @a) . "\n";' < input
```

Or spread out as a script-file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use List::Util 'shuffle';
local $/ = "";  ## paragraph mode
chomp(my @a = <>);
print join("\n\n", shuffle @a) . "\n";
```